# Neither PyTorch nor TensorFlow >= 2.0 have been found.Models won't be available and only tokenizers, configuration and file/data utilities can be used

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I am trying to install transformers using pip

```
pip install transformers
```

after import transformers

this error show

```
Neither PyTorch nor TensorFlow >= 2.0 have been found.Models won't be available and only tokenizers, configuration, and file/data utilities can be used.
```

although I install TensorFlow-GPU= 2.3.1 and using conda

system info

```
Windows 10 
python 3.6
cuda 10.1
tensorflow-gpu= 2.3.1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem after investigate for 10 hours

I installed tensorflow  by using `conda install tensorflow-gpu`

and transformers by using pip after remove tensorflow-gpu and install it by using pip

it works fine

Answer (score 10):

You need one of them PyTorch or Tensorflow.

You can check if tensorflow is installed or you can reinstall it

1. `pip uninstall tensorflow`
2. `pip install tensorflow==2.2.0`(you can install only tensorflow it worked same as tensorflow-gpu)
3. `pip uninstall transformers`
4. `pip install transformers==3.3.1`

If this doesn't solve it, try to upgrade your python to 3.7.8

Comment: It is `transformers` not `transformer`

Answer (score 3):

hello just want to add I use a M1 mac and got the same issue.  For M1 mac (or above) it is actually different packages.  The following requirments.txt works for me (with just python 3.10 + venv):

> tensorflow-macos==2.12.0
> tensorflow-metal==0.8.0
> transformers==4.29.2

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by installing PyTorch

```
pip install torch
```

or within Jupyter notebook

```
%pip install torch
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the requirements mentioned in requirement.txt using the command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```