# At least one of TensorFlow 2.0 or PyTorch should be installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I would like to use this Image to text model from [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/llava-hf/llava-1.5-7b-hf). When I run the code from the example I get an error:

```
from transformers import pipeline
from PIL import Image    
import requests

model_id = "llava-hf/llava-1.5-7b-hf"
pipe = pipeline("image-to-text", model=model_id)
url = "https://huggingface.co/datasets/huggingface/documentation-images/resolve/main/transformers/tasks/ai2d-demo.jpg"

image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
prompt = "USER: <image>\nWhat does the label 15 represent? (1) lava (2) core (3) tunnel (4) ash cloud\nASSISTANT:"

outputs = pipe(image, prompt=prompt, generate_kwargs={"max_new_tokens": 200})
print(outputs)
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: At least one of TensorFlow 2.0 or PyTorch should be installed. To install TensorFlow 2.0, read the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ To install PyTorch, read the instructions at https://pytorch.org/.
```

This error happens at loading the model in the `pipeline`. I understand that we have to use `Tensorflow` or `Pytorch`. So I installed it using `pip install tensorflow`:

```
Package                      Version
---------------------------- ----------
absl-py                      2.1.0
appnope                      0.1.4
asttokens                    2.4.1
astunparse                   1.6.3
cachetools                   5.3.2
certifi                      2024.2.2
charset-normalizer           3.3.2
comm                         0.2.1
debugpy                      1.6.7
decorator                    5.1.1
exceptiongroup               1.2.0
executing                    2.0.1
filelock                     3.13.1
flatbuffers                  23.5.26
fsspec                       2024.2.0
gast                         0.5.4
google-auth                  2.28.1
google-auth-oauthlib         1.2.0
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.62.0
h5py                         3.10.0
huggingface-hub              0.20.3
idna                         3.6
importlib-metadata           7.0.1
ipykernel                    6.29.2
ipython                      8.21.0
jedi                         0.19.1
jupyter_client               8.6.0
jupyter_core                 5.7.1
keras                        2.15.0
libclang                     16.0.6
Markdown                     3.5.2
MarkupSafe                   2.1.5
matplotlib-inline            0.1.6
mkl-fft                      1.3.8
mkl-random                   1.2.4
mkl-service                  2.4.0
ml-dtypes                    0.2.0
nest_asyncio                 1.6.0
numpy                        1.26.3
oauthlib                     3.2.2
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
packaging                    23.1
parso                        0.8.3
pexpect                      4.9.0
pickleshare                  0.7.5
pillow                       10.2.0
pip                          23.3.1
platformdirs                 4.2.0
prompt-toolkit               3.0.42
protobuf                     4.25.3
psutil                       5.9.8
ptyprocess                   0.7.0
pure-eval                    0.2.2
pyasn1                       0.5.1
pyasn1-modules               0.3.0
Pygments                     2.17.2
pytesseract                  0.3.10
python-dateutil              2.8.2
PyYAML                       6.0.1
pyzmq                        24.0.1
regex                        2023.12.25
requests                     2.31.0
requests-oauthlib            1.3.1
rsa                          4.9
safetensors                  0.4.2
setuptools                   68.2.2
six                          1.16.0
stack-data                   0.6.2
tensorboard                  2.15.2
tensorboard-data-server      0.7.2
tensorflow                   2.15.0
tensorflow-estimator         2.15.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.36.0
termcolor                    2.4.0
tokenizers                   0.15.2
tornado                      6.4
tqdm                         4.66.2
traitlets                    5.14.1
transformers                 4.38.1
typing_extensions            4.9.0
urllib3                      2.2.1
wcwidth                      0.2.13
Werkzeug                     3.0.1
wheel                        0.41.2
wrapt                        1.14.1
zipp                         3.17.0
```

So I'm using tensorflow `2.15.0` version. I'm using `Python 3.10.13` on a Mac intel. I followed this question: [Neither PyTorch nor TensorFlow >= 2.0 have been found.Models won't be available and only tokenizers, configuration and file/data utilities can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64337550/neither-pytorch-nor-tensorflow-2-0-have-been-found-models-wont-be-available) but installing the `tensorflow-gpu` with conda doesn't work. I followed the [installation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.15.0/installation) guide on HuggingFace but also doesn't work. I can't find a workaround for this. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check if TF can acess your GPU (If you have one)? Is your current error the same? What do you mean when you wrote "it doesn't work"? That's not a very informative description.

Comment: Hi @mhenning, thanks for your comment. I tried this code:`print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))` and it seems there are no GPUs available for me. And doesn't work I ment I tried running `conda install tensorflow-gpu` and tried my code again without success.

Comment: Do you expect a GPU to be found? In the [official installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) it is mentioned that `There is currently no official GPU support for MacOS.`. I don't know if there are any workaround, as I have no Mac.